# Can you clear my this doubt of conditional sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> 1. We are the best team that Konoha village **has to offer.**

In this, though I know it did not, I get a feeling like Konoha village has to offer them and they don't have a choice.It could say **Konoha village can offer**.I mean, does the sentence seem like the team is to be offered by the village on a condition?

Eg-

> 2. This is the money which I have to offer.
> 3. I have to do it.
> 4. He put the conditions to which she has to agree.

In these sentences, the **has/have to** brings a bit feeling of enforcement.She has to agree, she has no choice.She can agree, she has a choice.

Comment: The use of "to have" in the first block and the second block is completely different. The second implies need, the first implies possession. I think it's confusing because of the ambiguity.

Block 2: "I have to offer this to the gods"
Block 1: "This is what I have to offer". For "This is what I have to offer," you can only differentiate based on context whether you mean "this is what I need to offer" or "this is the thing that I possess that I can offer".

Comment: The expression **have to offer** has a special meaning: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/have-something-to-offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The best *X* (that) *Y* has to offer.

is a commonly used construction in which *has* indicates possession, not obligation.

For example, this article

> [The Best Food San Francisco Has to Offer](http://thehundreds.com/blog/imo-the-best-food-san-francisco-has-to-offer/)

It lists great places to eat in San Francisco (in the author's opinion). The first entry is *Pearl’s Deluxe Burgers*, where the author says you can find great burgers.
[image]
Looks good!

I believe 3 and 4 suggest obligation. 2 seems ambiguous to me. You intended it to express obligation, but I read it as

> I have this (amount of) money. I am capable of offering it.

For instance, if someone asks for a donation for a foundation on the side of the street, one might reply with 2.

So, I believe 1 is intended to suggest possession, not obligation. In other words, among all the teams in Konoha, that team is the best one and Konoha can offer it (if needed).